# In Google Sheets, how do we take a decimal feet value and turn it into properly formatted fractional Feet & Inches?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, fractions, superscript, unit-conversion

Been looking all over and nothing comes up as far as a Google Sheets formula.

Let's say we have a value of **3.6875 feet**. We can use the number format # ??/??, but it will give us a fractional value in feet (in this case, **3 11/16 feet**).

How do we "grab" the 11/16 and multiply it by 12 to get the inches value (8.25), and then the really tricky part, how do we display the whole enchilada as **3'8¹/⁴"** (yes, including the superscript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1**= 3.6875

**B1**=`INT(A1)&"'-"&TRIM(TEXT(ROUND(MOD(A1,1)*12*16,0)/16,"# ??/??")&"""")`

**Output**: 3'-8 1/4 "

**UPDATED:**

You can have a table to search the superscript

[image]

The idea to get the superscript: with above output (`3'-8 1/4"`): is to extract the fraction (1/4), search for the equivalent superscript in the table (¹/⁴), then replace it (`3'-8 ¹/⁴"`):

So basically we will need:

- REGEXEXTRACT
- VLOOKUP
- REGEXREPLACE

**SPREADSHEET DEMO**: [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19MkiGhiYB3_n6OtYtilyqXnTunQgNuZ3FfjMvddiSA4)

```
 =arrayformula(
  if(len(A2:A),INT(A2:A)&"'-             
     "&REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TEXT(ROUND(MOD(A2:A,1)*12*16,0)/16,"#??/??")&""""),
        "\d{1}\/\d+",
            VLOOKUP(IFNA(
    REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(TEXT(ROUND(MOD(A2:A,1)*12*16,0)/16,"# ??/??")&""""),
    "\d{1}\/\d+"),
    "0/0"),
            TABLE!A:B,2,0)),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did a little more digging regarding the superscript part, and found this: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-get-subscript-and-superscript-numbers-in-google-spreadsheets/

But can't figure out how to incorporate it programmatically in your formula. Any ideas?

Comment: See updated answer and demo spreadsheet.  If the answer solve your problem, you can up vote the answer and accept it.

Comment: WOW! You rock :) And thank you and excellent presentation of the solution. Sorry I didn't check back here sooner!